# Laravel 5.8 verification email module not sending EMAIL on Cpanel (Shared hosting)

Tags: laravel, smtp, cpanel, shared-hosting, email-verification

I'm working on a Project based on Laravel 5.8. I've enabled laravel built-in email verification module. Codes perfectly works on Localhost.

Now i've deployed my application on Cpanel (Shared Hosting) and configure domain webmail account in laravel .env file. But upon registration laravel show no error, but did not receive any email on Mailbox.

Here is my .env file code.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.ki****.pk
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@ki****.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

i've tried SSL/TSL configuration also, but same response; NO ERROR; NO EMAIL. On shared hosting we cannot change the mail_driver to **mail** and **send mail**

Comment: Do you use the same mail configuration in localhost?

Comment: @db1975 No, in localhost enviroment i've used gmail server  to send emails.

Comment: Test it in localhost with the mail.ki****.pk configuration. Perhaps you can see more errors. Do you test your configuration with an email client like Thunderbird?

Comment: Okay i'll check it

Comment: @db1975 i've tested the localhost with mail.ki****.pk configuration. it work on localhost.

Comment: @db1975 domain configuration also works in Thunderbird email client, same configuration work on localhost but did not work on Cpanel.

Comment: is your domain on the same server

Comment: @db1975 yes on the same server.

Comment: @1975 on localhost i've tried both mail server, gmail and domain server.

Comment: @1975 But on Hosting domain both mail servers are not working.